# A very small disc winds around a larger circular disc of radius $R$ connected to it by a string. How long is the spiral it travels?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, differential-geometry

A very small disc winds around a larger circular disc of radius $R$. It is connected to it by a string of length l that remains tight. What distance does it travel before it hits the larger disc of radius $R$ ? I've estimated that it is $2\pi(l-R)$ based on assuming a spiral is a little like a series of concentric circles.

Comment: A drawing could help. The starting point is where the center of the small (point?) circle is l distance from the center of the large circle? Do you know integrals?

Comment: I know integrals. But I'm having trouble formulating this as an integral without making big assumptions.

Comment: You need to define the small arc for integration based on Pythagorean formula.

Comment: Yes, a drawing is needed. I know all about cycloids and curves of pursuit, but I honestly do not understand your construction.

Comment: @TedShifrin It's this problem.  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/618389/why-is-the-radial-velocity-considered-zero/ There's a diagram there. It should simple to state. I'll try again. A all attached to a string, fully stretched, wraps around a disc of radius R that it is connected to. What is the length of the path of the spiral that the ball generates before it hits the disc?

Comment: You've been given a good starting point suggestion by Moti, which will help you to relate  an infinitesimal distance travelled to an infinitesimal reduction in the length of the string. In any case, you should show your attempt at the integrals.

Comment: By the way, the statement is imprecise. The choice of the direction of revolutions will affect the path length up to $\pm \pi l$, which is the distance travelled even before the string winds around the larger disk.

Comment: I assume that the starting point is when the small disc is stretching the disc. The first quarter of a circle is with radius of string length. Only than it starts warping around the large disc - for this part you need to use integration. You can get accuracy as far as you desire - no need for estimates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to add up your diminishing circle circumferences
is to use the formulas $2\pi R = \frac LN$ and  $N\pi = \frac{L}{2R},$
both of which are derived from $N = \frac{L}{2\pi R}.$

\begin{align}
\left(L - \frac LN\right)2\pi &+ \left(L - 2\frac LN\right)2\pi
 + \left(L - 3\frac LN\right)2\pi +  \cdots \\
&= \left(1 - \frac 1N\right)2\pi L + \left(1 - \frac 2N\right)2\pi L
 + \left(1 - \frac 3N\right)2\pi L +  \cdots \\
&= \left(N - 1\right)\frac{2\pi L}{N}
 + \left(N - 2\right)\frac{2\pi L}{N}
 + \left(N - 3\right)\frac{2\pi L}{N} +  \cdots \\
&= \left((N - 1) + (N - 2) + (N - 3) + \cdots + 1\right)\frac{2\pi L}{N} \\
&= \left(\frac{N(N - 1)}{2}\right)\frac{2\pi L}{N} \\
&= (N - 1)\pi L \\
&= N\pi L - \pi L \\
&= \frac{L^2}{2R} - \pi L. \\
\end{align}

But this is an underestimate, because at the beginning the end of the string is tracing a path of length approximately $L \theta$, where $\theta$ is the change in the angle of the string, although you have assumed it is only
$\left(1 - \frac 1N\right)L \theta.$
You could get a better approximation by wrapping the string around a regular polygon of $k$ sides and then letting $k$ increase to infinity
(effectively computing the integral of the path length as the string wraps around the circle);
the $\pi L$ term then drops out.

---

Your answer would also come up with the same sum except for a couple of errors.
The first error is that $2\pi \times 2\pi = 4\pi^2$ but you wrote $4\pi.$
The second error is on the very last step. Note that $2\pi N = \frac LR$
and $2\pi RN = L$ but $\pi(N + 1) = \frac{L}{2R} + \pi,$
so the result actually should be
\begin{align}
2\pi NL - 2\pi^2 RN(N+1)
 &= \frac{L^2}{R} - L\left(\frac{L}{2R} + \pi\right) \\
 &= \frac{L^2}{R} - \frac{L^2}{2R} - \pi L \\
 &= \frac{L^2}{2R} - \pi L.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. I didn't see this until right now.

Answer (score 2):

As stated on that physics page, it is easiest to consider the length and angle of the tight straight piece of rope.  If the angle $\theta$ starts at $0$ then winding the cord around gives a maximal angle $L/R$ (in radians).  The length of the straight piece of rope decreases linearly in $\theta$, so it is $$L(\theta) = L - R \theta.$$ Then the distance that the end of the rope travels is given by $$ \int_0^{L/R}L(\theta) \mathrm d \theta = \int_0^{L/R}(L - R \theta) \mathrm d \theta = \frac{L^2}{2R}.$$

This formula can also be obtained from an explicit parameterization of the path and calculating its length.  Again expressed in the angle $\theta$ the path can be given by $$\begin{eqnarray}
x(\theta) & = & R \sin(\theta) + (L - R \theta) \cos(\theta)\\
y(\theta) & = & -R \cos(\theta) + (L - R \theta) \sin(\theta)
\end{eqnarray}$$

The integrand of the path length integral simplifies quite a bit since $$\dot x(\theta)^2 + \dot y(\theta)^2 = (L - R \theta)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks. This looks good. It's going to take me awhile to understand it.

Comment: Maybe the explicit approach is the easiest. Otherwise you have to understand why the “moving center of rotation” has no effect on the outcome.

Comment: I'm surprised that the approximate answer was close to your exact answer. Now I'm wondering where the extra turn in my answer comes from. This is a very interesting problem.

Comment: I just got a chance to really look at this and it's brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

This has been updated with corrections given in the accepted answer.

Assuming $L>>R$.

Path length approximated assuming that the spiral is approximately a sum of circles with circumference $2\pi R$ for each revolution of the spiral.

Assume $N=\frac{L}{2\pi R}$ is an integer in suitable units for the particular problem.

$\text{sum of diminishing circle circumferences}=$

$(L-2\pi R)2\pi + (L-2\pi R -2\pi R)2\pi +...$

$=2\pi NL - 4\pi^2 R (1+2 +3+...N)=2\pi NL - 4\pi^2 R(N(N+1))/2$

$=\frac{L^2}{R} - 4\pi^2 R\frac{(\frac{L^2}{(2\pi R)^2}+\frac{L}{2\pi R}))}{2}$

$=\frac{L^2}{R} - (\frac{L^2}{2R}+\pi L))$

$=\frac{L^2}{2R}-\pi L$