# Summing Concentric Circles.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

This should be a simple problem. I want to sum lengths of concentric circles with the outer circle at radius L. Then each smaller circle is at radius $2\pi R$ less than the previous until the inner most circle hits $R$ and has circumference $2\pi R$. (This is intended to approximate a string wrapping around a disc R)

Assuming $L>>R$.

Assume $N=\frac{L}{2\pi R}$ is an integer in suitable units for the particular problem.

$\text{sum of diminishing circle circumferences}=$

$(L-2\pi R)2\pi + (L-2\pi R -2\pi R)2\pi +...$

$=2\pi NL - 4\pi^2 R (1+2 +3+...N)=2\pi NL - 4\pi^2 R(N(N+1))/2$

$=\frac{L^2}{2R} +\pi L$

Note: This problem was also answered here (where was considered as an approximation to a more difficult problem):

[A very small disc winds around a larger circular disc of radius $R$ connected to it by a string. How long is the spiral it travels?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4050833/a-very-small-disc-winds-around-a-larger-circular-disc-of-radius-r-connected-to)

Comment: What do you mean by "lengths of circles". Do you mean their circumference?

Comment: @AnayAggarwal yes.

Comment: L/R can not be an integer the way it works.  Please see the answer.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same question as [A very small disc winds around a larger circular disc of radius R
connected to it by a string. How long is the spiral it travels?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4050833/139123)

Comment: @DavidK No. This is based on that. But it's not the same question.

Comment: What's different about it? At least as a courtesy you should have linked to the previous question and explained why this one is not the same. You can still edit this question and fix that.

Comment: @DavidK But that is a much more difficult question about the length of a spiral. This really is very different. I didn't want to distract from this question.

Comment: My answer to your first question answers the entire part of this question up to $2\pi NL - 4\pi R (1+2 +3+...N)=2\pi NL - 4\pi R(N(N+1))/2$. The part after that provides new ways to get wrong results, so I guess that's new, but you don't give enough intermediate steps for me to spot exactly where the errors creep in.

Comment: I see now, the other difference between the questions is that you gave this question as an **answer** to the other question. That's confusing. At least, it confused me.

Comment: I honestly didn't think it was even close to being right. I'm shocked that the approach seems to have come up with almost the exact answer. I had actually given up on that problem and just wanted to add circles together.  I edited the question and added a link to that page. Thanks for helping with that. I spent two days thinking about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum/minimum radii are $(L,R)$. A finite thickness of circles in a continuous tape  packing is assumed and taken into account :

Let the thickness be $t$ and let each circle contact the next without a gap. Then
$$ n= \dfrac{L-R}{t}, \text {total length from each average circle  }= 2n \pi \dfrac{R+L}{2}$$

This can be also seen as total concentric circles lateral edge area divided by $t$ to be its total unwound length:

$$= \dfrac{\pi (L^2-R^2)}{t}.$$

Comment: That's interesting. When you set this equal to $\frac{L^2}{2R}$ (the answer we found when approximating the spiral) and solve for $t$ you get $t= 2πR- (\pi 2 R^3)/L^2)$ which is nearly $2\pi R$ as it should be.