# Can I use a Monte Carlo method (or any other unusual methods) to find this path length?

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

I'm trying to determine this path length by as many distinct and unusual methods as possible.

[A very small disc winds around a larger circular disc of radius $R$ connected to it by a string. How long is the spiral it travels?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4050833/a-very-small-disc-winds-around-a-larger-circular-disc-of-radius-r-connected-to)

The path is that of the end of a tight string as the string wraps around a disc of radius R. Moving perpendicular to the strings length.

I've only seen Monte Carlo used to approximate an area. (ratios of areas actually)

Comment: Monte Carlo methods are all based on random sampling, but I don't see a trivial formulation that could be sampled in a random fashion (compared to e.g. integrals of type $F = \int \dots \int f(x_1, x_2, \dots x_n) d x_1 \, d x_2 \, \dots d x_n$, which *are* often estimated using Monte Carlo integration).  (The explicit integral in the other answer is trivial and known; there is no reason to try and apply Monte Carlo integration to it.)

Comment: What is the motivation for this?