# I'm trying to calculate the covariant derivatives of this rotating system to discover the fictitious forces the particle feels.

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

This should be straightforward. The only thing unusual about this transformation from $(\theta, L(\theta)) \to (x,y)$ is that the transformation can be parameterized using one variable. But, it seems to me, that the math should still work. It's still just moving to a rotating system (similar to [this problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/536057/288901) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/615900/288901)). My answer seems reasonable too. 1.Am I trying to do something that is not possible? 2.Am I making a mistake? Is there an easier way to do this?

$L(\theta)\equiv L-R\theta$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
x(\theta,L(\theta) ) & = & R \sin(\theta) + (L - R \theta) \cos(\theta)\\
y(\theta,L(\theta) ) & = & -R \cos(\theta) + (L - R \theta) \sin(\theta)
\end{eqnarray}$$

$\equiv$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
x(\theta,L(\theta)) & = & R \sin(\theta) + L(\theta) \cos(\theta)\\
y(\theta,L(\theta)) & = & -R \cos(\theta) + L(\theta) \sin(\theta)
\end{eqnarray}$$

The physics behind this transformation comes from [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4050833/a-very-small-disc-winds-around-a-larger-circular-disc-of-radius-r-connected-to).

Transforming $g_{cartesian} \to g_{\text{this rotating system}}$

$g_{\theta \theta} = L(\theta)^2 \to g^{\theta \theta} = \frac{1}{L(\theta)^2}$

$g_{rr}=1$

$\Gamma^{\theta} _{\theta \theta}= \frac{-R}{L^2}$

$\Gamma^{\theta} _{\theta L}= \frac{-R}{L}$

$F^r =0$

$F^{\theta}=\ddot{\theta}^2  - \frac{R}{L^2} \omega^2 -\frac{2R}{L} \omega^2=\ddot{\theta}^2-\omega^2(\frac{R}{L^2}+\frac{2R}{L})$

The units in the middle term don't match up.

Any help would be appreciated.